# How to use multiple tick providers (frame & fixed) with Ash entity framework?

Tags: actionscript-3, game-engine, ash

It's a common practice to make rendering calculations on frame update and physics calculations at a fixed interval of time. I don't understand how to do this in Ash. All examples of Game objects I've seen just use one `ITickProvider` (could be FixedTickProvider or FrameTickProvider), which calls `engine.update()` on each tick. What if, for example, I want to update my rendering systems at 60 fps, but update game logic at a fixed interval of time, in case there's lag?

```
tickProvider = new FrameTickProvider( container );
tickProvider.add( engine.update );
tickProvider.start();
```

Some ideas...

- Can I update groups of systems separately?
- Should I use 2 engines?

Comment: You can calculate time delta in your PhysicsSystem.update() method and just do nothing if delta is less than your desired interval.

Answer (score 0):

Without entering specific considerations about ash framework, there is many ways to handle physic & graphic engine update, which do not necessarily depend on the framework you're using.
First of all, unless you're making an AIR mobile app targeting only devices with sufficient hardware requirements, you cannot assume a solid 60fps framerate (or any solid framrate).
This leaves you with several options:

- update physic engine with fixed delta t, in this case any missed frame will slow down the game physic. Not great
- measure actual delta t between last frames and update physic engine accordingly to compensate the delay of the previous frame. This should be sufficient in mostcase
- if for some reason your physic engine requires fixed increments (for example `updatePhysic(1/30);`
  gives a too different result from `updatePhysic(1/60); updatePhysic(1/60);`, or if you need   perfectly framerate-independent reproductible physic, like computing replays, or keeping networked clients physic synced) replace `updatePhysic(dT);` by 
  `for(var i:int = 0; i< dT * 60; ++i) updatePhysic(1/60);`
  (if delta t is not always multiple of 1/60 implementation you should accumulate the rest of the division for next update)
- If you need optimal performance and best use of multi-core CPU's, you could consider updating the physic engine in a separate worker, but flash player support, debugging tools and sharing data between the workers are still experimental!

In any case, I don't see the point in

> I want to update my rendering systems at 60 fps, but update game logic at a fixed interval of time, in case there's lag?

since if there's a "lag", it means display won't be updated at 60 fps, and even if it was (in the eventuality that you perform physics in a separated worker) it would be displaying the same frame again.

To sum up, you might need to run the physic engine "faster" than the graphic engine, but never the contrary.

Also, in actionscript, you cannot trigger an tick faster than the actual framerate :
any call to Timer, setTimeout, setInterval... will be at most synchronized with the display, but never faster, this is why you have to call the physic engine several time manually inside the main loop, instead of just setting a tick to 60 fps for instance